# Modify php default function parameter

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have a function [yaz_wait()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.yaz-wait.php) which looks like this
`mixed yaz_wait ([ array &$options ] )` and as parameters, it has `options` as you can see in the linked documentation.

One of the `options` is `timeout` value which I want to use and edit from its default 15 seconds to some other value.

I have tried

`yaz_wait(array("timeout" => 30));`

but I get `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference...`

I am not sure how exactly should I insert this parameter into this function since I have never met with such parameter type (haven't been working with php a lot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a function with `&` parameter in a function this means it will return a reference to the variable instead of the value.

In other words, you need to pass a variable that the function will attempt to change(or do whatever with it). Since you aren't passing a variable, you get a fatal error.

Try changing your code to:

```
$some_arr = array("timeout" => 30);
yaz_wait($some_arr);
```